# Orphan keys in Redis

Tags: redis

It appears to be very easy to create orphan keys in Redis.

Is this just something that Redis provides a mechanism to deal with?

Should you be super careful to enable convenient clean-up queries to be run (like adding keys to sets specifically for later housekeeping use)?

Or do users periodically "clean" their instances using heuristics like last-access time?

Comment: You could set a key's TTL with expire, see: https://redis.io/commands/expire

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to not create orphan keys or you need to enable caching

https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Of course if you're using Redis as a cache, it should not be your sole data sink. Instead it would be a frontend to a fully persisted database

Redis can't know your key lifetimes since a key is not anonymous. If you have some method to determine it then you can schedule a kind of ad hoc GC scan periodically, but you'll have to implement the logic for that based on your system's rules

Comment: Thank you. Redis is my primary database.